# PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync duplicate channel

Tags: c#, push-notification, win-universal-app, windows-10, azure-notificationhub

We use Azure Notifications Hub to manage notifications registrations. Every time user launches application, we call PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync and then RegisterNativeAsync of NotificationHub to register channel uri, returned by first with some tags like "Username" and "InstallId" - that is unique per app installation. Then from back-end we send notifications using these tags.

But we have noticed problem - when user hard-resets device, the previous channel registration stays active in notification hub. In that case user receives duplicate notifications by his "Username" tag. "InstallId" doesn't help in that case, as it is changing with new app installation.

We have thought about managing channels server-side. But that will not solve the problem.

Maybe anyone has some suggested work-around? 
Also, we don't know what information does PushNotificationChannelManager use when creating new or returning existing channel? Does it use some device information?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can send the backend the device unique Id along with the installation Id. The device id will not change upon hard reset.

```
private string GetDeviceUniqueID()
    {
        HardwareToken token = HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken(null);
        IBuffer hardwareId = token.Id;

        HashAlgorithmProvider hasher = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm("MD5");
        IBuffer hashed = hasher.HashData(hardwareId);

        string hashedString = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToHexString(hashed);
        return hashedString;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. We have thought on using "ASHWID" HardwareToken as you have suggested, but we have noticed when user installs Windows 10 insider version, Device Name is also sometimes updated. And we are afraid that HardwareToken would change in that case. Need to check that.

Comment: Have checked https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj553431 and think that using HardwareToken is not an option, as we need 100% solution.

Comment: using ASHWID in combination with installation Id should help you create a filter rule to avoid duplicate registration in the Notification Hub:

If user install the app (new installation id) in a machine with known ASHWID, you wont create new registration if there is one exists.

if user open the app with known installation id but new ASHWID (indicate hardware change), check if the hardware change is critical (e.g: HDD replacement) to decide if you need new registration or not.